# Problems connecting to a db2/as400 database in Python with pyodbc and ibm_db

Tags: python, db2, pyodbc

I am trying to connect a Juypter NoteBook running in PyCharm to my companies database. Here is the code I am using.

```
dsn = 'DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=DATABASE.HERE.COM;UID=user;PWD=password'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn, autocommit=True)
```

For Obvious reasons I changed the log ins and database address
But when I run it I get this error code

`Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')`

Any ideas what is going on with it? The driver version is 13.00.14.00

I also tried using ibm_db to connect

```
dsn_driver = "IBM i Access ODBC DRIVER"
dsn_database = "DATABASE"
dsn_hostname = "DATABASE.HERE.COM"
dsn_uid = "user"
dsn_pwd = "password"

dsn = (
    "DRIVER={0};"
    "DATABASE={1};"
    "HOSTNAME={2};"
    "UID={3};"
    "PWD={4};"

).format(dsn_driver, dsn_database, dsn_hostname, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd)

conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
```

Had no luck with that either
I got this error code.

```
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "10.244.130.11".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001  SQLCODE=-30081
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Which operating system runs your pycharm? Don't you need to specify the tcpip port number in the connection string?e.g PORT=446;` (for unencrypted) or PORT=448 (for encrypted connections).?  Is that port opened in your local operating-system for input and output traffic for tcp (e.g. Windows advanced firewall rules, or whatever firewall is running on your local operating-system running pychar).